# Change Button text When Status Is approved in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, button, html-table

I am binding the table using ng-repeat in angularjs here is my table

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Sr. no.
      </th>

      <th>
        Title
      </th>

      <th>
        Image
      </th>
      <th>
        Category
      </th>
      <th>
        PostedOn
      </th>
      <th>
        Created By
      </th>
      <th>
        Status
      </th>
      <th>
        Change Status
      </th>

    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="obj in PostedBlogList | filter:searchText" ng-show="PostedBlogList.length">
      <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td><a ng-href="{{'//'+obj.PageUrl }}">{{obj.Title}}</a></td>
      <td>
        <img style="width:90px" ng-show="obj.Image" src="{{obj.Image}}">
        <img style="width:90px" ng-show="!obj.Image" src="/images/mail.png">
      </td>
      <td>
        {{obj.CategoryName}}
      </td>

      <td>
        {{obj.CreatedDate}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{obj.FirstName}}({{obj.UserType}})
      </td>
      <td>
        {{obj.IsActive ? 'Approved ' : 'Pending'}}
      </td>
      <td>

        <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" ng-click="ToActiveBlog(obj.Id)" ng-bind="btnactivate" type="submit" value="Activate"></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="PostedBlogList.length==0">

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In second last td I am setting the value approved and pending.

```
  {{obj.IsActive ? 'Approved ' : 'Pending'}}
```

Below td there is a button

```
<td>
  <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" ng-click="ToActiveBlog(obj.Id)" type="submit" value="Activate"></button>
</td>
```

Which has an `activate` text on it 
How can I set the button text "Inactivate" when my status is approved in angularjs?

Comment: Make sure you format the code in your question

Comment: `value="{{obj.IsActive ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate'}}"`

Comment: same way as you are setting  {{obj.IsActive ? 'Approved ' : 'Pending'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-value` attribute instead of value attribute in the button element. This is specially for Angularjs set value for input elements.

```
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" ng-click="ToActiveBlog(obj.Id)" ng-bind="btnactivate" type="submit" ng-value="obj.IsActive ? 'Activate' : 'Inactivate'"></button>
</td>
```

or else using `ng-if`

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree
>   based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates
>   to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a
>   clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

```
<td ng-if=obj.IsActive>
    <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" ng-click="ToActiveBlog(obj.Id)" ng-bind="btnactivate" type="submit" value="Activate"></button>
</td>

<td ng-if=!obj.IsActive>
    <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" ng-click="ToActiveBlog(obj.Id)" ng-bind="btnactivate" type="submit" value="Inactivate"></button>
</td>
```

Comment: text is not changing sir

Comment: I have applied both solution

Comment: @Gaurav_0093 - I updated answer with ng-value please check

Answer (score 1):

You can use string interpolation in same way

```
 <button ng-click="ToActiveBlog(obj.Id)">{{obj.IsActive ? 'inactivate' : 'Activate'}}</button>
```

Comment: "Inactivate" instead of "deactivate" to match the requirements ?!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following, i think it should work. As i did not had the access to post comment hence im posting it as an answer

```
 <td>
    <button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" ng-click="ToActiveBlog(obj.Id)"  type="submit" value={{obj.IsActive ? 'Approved ' : 'Pending'}}>
  </button>
  </td>
```